# vim find buffer by absolute path

Tags: vim, vimscript

How can I find a buffer in vimscript when I have an absolute path, and as you know vim buffer names can be relative path? Is there a function for that?

Comment: "related path" -> you mean "relative path"?

Answer (score 2):

The `bufnr()` function can find buffers (and return its number). Like `bufname()`, this can take the queried buffer name in several forms (cp. `:help bufname()`):

> ```
>   A full match is preferred, otherwise a match at the start, end
>   or middle of the buffer name is accepted.  If you only want a
>   full match then put "^" at the start and "$" at the end of the
>   pattern.
> ```

So, one example would be

```
:echo bufnr('^C:\path\to\file.txt$')
```

Also, you can convert between relative and absolute paths via the `fnamemodify()` function.